# JavaFX delay execution until added to scene

Tags: javafx-2

Sometimes there are actions one wants to take on a Node but one needs access to the Scene or for other reasons needs it to be added to the Scene first.

In Swing, I could use a hierarchy change listener to do this. Is there some type of notification or event when a Node is added to the hierarchy so that getScene will return non-null?

Comment: For situations like this, I like to add all the components I will need for the scene and then manipulate their isVisible() and isDisabled() properties.   If your scene is so dynamically generated that it cannot be manipulated in this way, then you'll have to respond to events on sceneProperty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a [ChangeListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/value/ChangeListener.html) to the node's [sceneProperty](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#sceneProperty%28%29) to be notified to changes of the scene the node is attached to, including when the scene property changes from null to some value.